# Connecting DataFactory to Lotus notes DB

Tags: azure, lotus-notes, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to connect to lotus notes DB which is there in On-Prem. There is no built-in connector available in Azure DataFactory V2) to connect to it.

I've read an article about how to get data from lotus notes:

1. Using ODBC driver connection.
2. .Net code to read it.

Did anyone tried above possibility ? If so let us know whether it is possible, and if so what are Pros & Cons.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but could you use REST calls, to use Domino Access Services? See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/LotusSupport/entry/Whats_New_in_Domino_Access_Services

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ODBC connector from data data factory? I have never had to use it, but im pretty sure it will work as any other.

Just go to Connections, click on New, then type ODBC and fill the form! Make sure to select the on premise integration runtime when filling the form, so it connects through that to the database.

Here are some screenshots to help you:

[image: New Linked Service]

[image: ODBC Selection]

[image: Fill the form]

Hope this helped!

Comment: Connecting to domino would require the notes sql odbc driver, wouldn't it ? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/index.html

Comment: Im not sure if it is mandatory, but it doesnt hurt to have the link at hand if the regular odbc fails :)